# How to load java script file in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loading

I just started studying mongoDB. I need help in loading **java script file  into my database**.
I currently using mongoDB in windows operating system.Used the below commands

> mongo 127.0.0.1/database database.js

**SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (shell):1**

Any help appreciated.Thanks in advance.......

Comment: You probably have a javascript syntax error inside your database.js file.

Comment: In mongo shell you can execute load(...), it execute your js file http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/load/

Comment: Check your code for a syntax error using: http://www.jslint.com/